# Developer tool IE/Edge change to full new .css style

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

We only have Internet Explorer at work. For a feedback I'd like to change the whole .css file on the developer tool so I only need to send the new .css file to my boss  and copy paste it into his IE. Is there any solution I can use to make it simple to show him the changes r is there a possibility to do it in the developer tool?
I do not have direct access to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you do not have direct access to CSS file but If you are able to open web page in Internet Explorer then you can go to the **File** menu and **Save As** the web page to the desired location.

[image]

The Web page will be saved with HTML, CSS, JS and images.

Then you can easily modify the CSS file and make a test in IE to view the changes.

Then you can share the modified file with other users. This is the correct and proper way to solve this issue instead of modifying the code in developer tools.